# PHP Video Upload Form Time Out

Tags: php, forms, video, upload, timeout

I am attempting to work on a simple script that will allow me to upload different types of media to a web server, these include currently video and photograph formats. The problem I am having is when I attempt to upload a video, the form on the page seems to fail to submit. As in I click the submit button and the page hangs for a moment then returns to form being displayed as if not submitted.

I have attempted to increase the fileszie in the $max_file_size and this has had no effect, it does not seem to be reaching the point at where this has used.

I have also searched on the internet and it suggested I use the "ini_set" features listed at the top of my code to rule out any PHP form submission issues - these seem to of had no effect.

```
<?php
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '45M');  
ini_set('post_max_size', '45M');  
ini_set('max_input_time', 30000);  
ini_set('memory_limit', '45M');

$file_types_array=array("avi", "JPG", "jpeg", "flv", "mpeg", "FLV"); 
// File Size maximum set in bytes
$max_file_size=35645847; 
// Test directory created on the server to allow for uploads
// potential to direct to user spercific areas for secuirty concerns
$upload_dir="uploads\\"; 
// Holds Unix Time in seconds, used for a unique stamp per upload to
// avoud multiple images/videos having the same ID
$stamp = time();
// Unique User ID - 123 for testing
$UserID = 123;
/* If the form is not submitted, display the form */
if(!isset($_POST["submitted"])){ 
    $form = "<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>Upload files:<br /><input type='hidden' name='submitted' value='TRUE' id='".time()."'><input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='".$max_file_size."'>"; 
        $form .= "<input type='file' name='file[]'><br />"; 
    $form .= "<input type='submit' value='Upload'><br />Valid file type(s): "; 
    // Displays the valid file types set in $file_types_array
        for($x=0;$x<count($file_types_array);$x++){ 
            if($x<count($file_types_array)-1){ 
                $form .= $file_types_array[$x].", "; 
            }else{ 
                $form .= $file_types_array[$x]."."; 
            } 
        } 
    $form .= "</form>"; 
    echo($form); 
}else{ 
    foreach($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $key => $value){
        if($_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]!=""){ 
            if($value==UPLOAD_ERR_OK){ 
                $fileID = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]; 
                $filename = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]); 
                $filenameext = $filename[count($filename)-1]; 

    // Checks for file extension        
    $file_ext_allow = FALSE; 
    for($x=0;$x<count($file_types_array);$x++){ 
        if($filenameext==$file_types_array[$x]){ 
            $file_ext_allow = TRUE; 
        } 
    } 
    if($file_ext_allow){ 
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"][$key]<$max_file_size){ 
        $fileWrite = $UserID."_".$stamp.".".$filenameext; 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key], $upload_dir.$fileWrite)){ 
                echo("File uploaded successfully.<br />"); 
            }else{  // Catch for unprepared error
                echo($fileID." was not successfully uploaded<br />"); 
            } 
            }else{ // Catch for File Size too big
                echo($fileID." was too big, not uploaded<br />"); 
            } 
            }else{ // Catch for bad File Name
                echo($fileID." had an invalid file extension, not uploaded<br />"); 
            } 
            }else{ // Successful Output
                echo($fileID." was not successfully uploaded<br />"); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
?>
```

Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated as I have been staring at this one piece of code for a little too long now ....

Regards,

Comment: Just to be clear: you are able to upload images? And what about small videos?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use PHP to upload large files, I would look at using something like [this](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) or use HTML5 to upload large files. You're limited to what you can do with plain old form uploads and the end users doesn't know what's happening.